# Как сделать код валидным?

Tags: html, html5

Добрый вечер.

Проверяю код на валидность, и вот какая проблема возникла:

```
  Error Line 340, Column 68: Element figcaption not allowed as child of element a in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
                                    <figcaption style="height: 70px;" class="item-description">
Contexts in which element figcaption may be used:
As the first or last child of a figure element.
Content model for element a:
Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.
```

И ошибок с данным тегом аж 8 штук, все остальные ошибки поправил сам, а с этим что-то никак :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633350/getting-an-error-in-w3c-markup-validation-when-trying-to-get-a-whole-figure-el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написано:

> Element figcaption not allowed as child of element a in this context.

Видимо, в вашем HTML-файле тэг `figcaption` вложен куда-то не туда, в то место, где ему не положено находиться.

Можете показать код?

Comment: Да, конечно, вот код элеманта <figure> 

  <figure>
   <div class="mediaholder">
    
      <a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>">

       <div class="hovercover">
        <div class="hovericon"><i class="hoverlink"></i></div>
       </div>
      </a>
     <?endif;?>
    <?endif?>
   </div>
   
   <a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>">
    <figcaption class="item-description">
                                   ................
    </figcaption>
   </a>

 
  </figure>

Answer (score 0):

засунь весь тег <figure> в тег <a>